# Stripe - Where to get source_transaction id when making transfer?

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments

I would like to make a direct transfer from a user card to connected accounts. For that I have to indicate the source_transaction field.

```
await stripe.transfers.create({
          amount: amount,
          currency: "eur",
          destination: "{connected_account1}",
          transfer_group: "{ORDER1}",
          source_transaction: // How to get this information ?
        });
```

**Here is the information I get from my app (PaymentMethod):**

[image: PaymentMethod Object]

What do I have to do to get the `source_transaction` with the informations I get on the PaymentMethod Object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `PaymentMethod` object represents the payment instrument used to pay. For example if you collect card details you will get a card `PaymentMethod` (pm_123) but it could also be for SEPA Debit or Alipay. This is unrelated to `source_transaction`.

To make a Transfer to a connected account you need to have funds in your platform account's balance on Stripe. In the flow you describe, you wouldn't use your own balance and instead you tie the Transfer to the release of funds associated with a payment already made.

This flow is called Separate Charges and Transfers and is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers). In this flow, you charge a customer for $10 via the `PaymentIntent` API. Then you separately create a `Transfer` to the connected account for say $8. The `source_transaction` here should be the id of the `Charge` (ch_123) created as a result of the payment.

The Charge id would be in the `charges` collection on the `PaymentIntent` once it has succeeded and it's always the first charge in the array (most recent). So if you already have a `PaymentIntent` in memory in a variable called `payment_intent` you would need `payment_intent.charges.data[0].id` and that would map to `ch_123` to pass inside `source_transaction`.

Comment: Thank you for this very well constructed question. I did a PaymentIntent, only the data array in the charges object is empty, so there is no id. Do you have an idea why it's empty ?

Comment: That's because you never confirmed the PaymentIntent successfully so for now you just created an "empty shell" to show your intent to collect funds. You first have to confirm it client-side with card details collected via Elements. You likely want to read https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: I try to execute StripePayment.confirmPaymentIntent(...) on the client side right after creating the paymentIntent. But I get the following error: No such payment_intent: 'pi_...'. Its seems I can't confirm the paymentIntent before do something with it.

Comment: I saw in the charges object a field: url: '/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1IPlyIC0a5######'. Maybe I can retrieve the charge to get the payment_intent.charges.data[0].id ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand your last 2 questions and what's blocking you. You might want to contact Stripe support directly for help instead: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: You were right :) I needed to confirm the paymentIntent before make the transfer.

Comment: Ah awesome, glad you got it fixed!